# Let $K,L$ be two rings and $g:K\to L$ be a homomorphism. Now $a\in K$ is zero divisor if and only if $g(a)$ is a zero divisor.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K,L$ be two rings and $g:K\to L$ be a homomorphism.
Now
$a\in K$ is zero divisor if and only if $g(a)$ is a zero divisor.

For the right direction:

Let $a$ be a zero divisor $\exists x\in K$ s.t. $ax=0$ and since $g$ is a homomorphism $g(a)g(x)=g(ax)=g(0)=0$ so $g(a)$ is a zero divisor.

However in the converse I am having trouble,

if $g(a)$ is a zero divisor $\exists y\in L$ s.t. $g(a)y=0$ but since $g$ is not necessarily onto, I don't know $y\in g(K)$ or not.

Or if I try to prove not $p\Rightarrow q$ but $q'\Rightarrow p'$

since I don't know $ax$ is not in kernel $g(ax)$ might be zero so I cannot prove it.

Comment: I don't think it's true without some extra hypotheses on $g$ (such as $g$ is an isomorphism).  For example, consider the case where $g$ is the quotient map $\mathbb{R}[x, y] \to \mathbb{R}[x,y] / \langle xy \rangle$; then $x$ is not a zero divisor but $g(x)$ is.  Or, consider the quotient map $\mathbb{R}[x, y] / \langle xy \rangle \to \mathbb{R}[x, y] / \langle y \rangle$ where $x$ is a zero divisor but $g(x)$ is not since the codomain is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if $g$ is onto , the converse is false: the canonical map
$$\mathbf Z\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z,\quad a\longmapsto a+6\mathbf Z$$
maps $2\times 3$ to $2\bmod 6\times 3\bmod 6=0\bmod 6$, yet $\mathbf Z$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

Neither direction is true in general.

For example, the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$ (which is injective) sends the nonzero divisor $2$ to a zero divisor.

Also, the (non-injective!) ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(xy) \to \mathbb{Z}[x]$ sending $x$ and $y$ to $x$ and $0$ respectively sends the zero divisor $x$ to a nonzero divisor.